# Keep int value in array length

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Listview and list of color. I want to change each list items background using colors in list. For doing that, I create simple recursive function that helps me giving index number for avoid out of index error.

For example: I have 5 colors in my list and if I try to access more than 4th color index, then it shows an "out of array" error. So my function does that.

My recursive function:

```
getColorIndex(int index) {
    return index <= 4 ? index : getColorIndex(index - 5);
}
```

I am wondering is there any native function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about modulo (%) which is a very common concept in computer science and general mathematics: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/num/operator_modulo.html

So your method can be rewritten into:

```
void main() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    print('index = $i | Color Index: ${getColorIndex(i)}');
  }
}

int getColorIndex(int index) => index % 5;
```

```
index = 0 | Color Index: 0
index = 1 | Color Index: 1
index = 2 | Color Index: 2
index = 3 | Color Index: 3
index = 4 | Color Index: 4
index = 5 | Color Index: 0
index = 6 | Color Index: 1
index = 7 | Color Index: 2
index = 8 | Color Index: 3
index = 9 | Color Index: 4
```

But what you should normally do is: `myList[index % myList.length]` which is the recommended way to do it since it the most clear way.

Comment: Yours better than mine thanks for that but im looking for some core dart function or maybe method of list class. I didnt write that so its my fault.

Comment: Normally, you would not even declare a method for this but just do: `myList[index % myList.length]`. If this is too ugly for you, you can also add an extension method on `List` to handle it.

Comment: It is late night and i think my brain isnt working. It is that simple. Thank you for your all help. It is what i am looking for. Simple and clean.

Comment: I didnt know this 'extension method' stuff and T keyword but I have learnt now. You have taught me more than my teacher :) Thank you sir.

Comment: Personally I find just using modulo in the first place much cleaner and more descriptive, and creating a function for such a simple operation (even an extension method) to be the ugly option. To each their own, I suppose.

Comment: I agree with you. This is why i decided to ask for someone because i didnt like my solution way.